# How can I process Avro Container data with different versions of schema?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, avro

I have months' worth of data from a single domain stored in HDFS in Avro Container files. Each file has the schema for all the data in that file, of course. How do I process all the data using Hive or Pig? It seems both Hive and Pig need the avsc file of some form of table structure definition up front. i.e. even if I use Avro tools to extract avsc from each file I will have to load each dataset using a different avsc file and I cannot process all of them using one job or DDL + Query.

Isn't it possible for Hive and Pig to pull the avsc at runtime based on the Avro Container file it is processing? Is it already implemented and I'm not finding it or too difficult to implement?